# Difference between extending interface and intersection type for props extending RouteComponentProps in Typescript React class component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-router

What is the difference between an extended interface and an intersection type in Typescript? I don't understand how the resulting type differs, especially for the simple case of extending non-overlapping properties.

In the following example of typing a React class component's props, why would the extended interface fail to correctly extend `RouteComponentProps` (which is also an interface) but an intersection type results in the correct typing/properties?

```js
import React, {PureComponent} from 'react';
import {RouteComponentProps, withRouter} from 'react-router-dom';

// Interface fails to extend the properties
interface Props extends RouteComponentProps {}

// But if we used an intersection type, that works
// type Props = {} & RouteComponentProps

class MyComponent extends PureComponent<Props> {
    constructor(props: Props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        console.log('All props', this.props); // Prints all props including routing-related

        // Error here: Property 'history' does not exist on type 'Props'.  TS2339
        console.log('History - ', this.props.history);
        
        return <p>Hello World!</p>;
    }
}

export default withRouter(MyComponent);
```

The IDE (VSCode) can apparently get the correct type/properties with intellisense (using the dot operator to show autocomplete options). However, the Typescript compiler gives the error

```
Property 'history' does not exist on type 'Props'.  TS2339
```

I don't understand why (since I thought that the resulting type should extend the same properties), but if `Props` is defined as an intersection type with `RouteComponentProps`,  then it works.

```js
type Props = {} & RouteComponentProps;
```

Why is this? What is happening such that the interface extension isn't pulling down the properties as expected?

In this simpler toy example of interface extension, everything works as expected with no TS compiler errors.

```js
interface A {
    x: string;
}

interface B extends A {
    y: string;
}

function doSomething(something: B) {
    console.log(something.x);
}

doSomething({x: 'Whatever', y: 'Whatever'});
```

So I'm left confused at how interface extension differs from type intersection.

To reiterate the main question:
What is the difference between an extended interface and an intersection type in Typescript?

## Trying the Example on TS Playground

Trying the code example in TS Playground on 3.9.7 ([convenience link with code and on 3.9.7](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=3.9.7#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)), the `.d.ts` definitions of the imports actually get picked up which is pretty cool, but then I get some non-obvious console errors, as well as sidebar errors that don't actually show up. See this screenshot which demonstrates both:
[image: TS Playground code example with console and sidebar errors]

Comment: There is not really a difference for these purposes as both say that `Props` has all of the properties of `RouteComponentProps`.  When I copy and paste your code into the Typescript playground I'm not seeing the error, so I'm not sure what's going wrong here.

Comment: @LindaPaiste Good idea to check on the TS playground. I'm on TS 3.9.7. In the playground for the class component code, it correctly pulls down the `.d.ts` definitions for the imports, but can't emit JS, shows a badge for 73 errors in the sidebar but no actual errors are displayed, and the console has multiple instances of this error: `index.js:24 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Debug Failure. False expression: Paths must either both be absolute or both be relative`. Can you confirm that you used the top code block (the class component) and that you didn't see any sidebar or console errors? TY!

Comment: Also note that for me, the code itself doesn't get highlighted with red squigglies or anything. I'm not getting any feedback from the playground other than the error badge count and the console errors that I'm not what they're for. 
For convenience, the `bit.ly` shortened url is at `/34i3PYB` (Sorry, it had to be URL shortened because the code encoded into the URL made it too long to post the full URL. Also, SO wouldn't let me post a bitly link whole. The link is to a playground of my code example with TS 3.9.7). Hopefully others are able to reproduce what I'm seeing.